# File Vs Inpustream in jersey 1.x jaxrs resource

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-1.0

Have a need to provide file upload feature using Jax-Rs Jersey-1.x resource.
I want to know if its better to create the method with "File" as parameter or "InputStream"?

Resource will accept `application/octet-stream` content-type and not tied to form-data.
it will need to work with small to huge size (upto gig) files.

want to know if using `InputStream` as method parameter over `File` (or vice versa) has any advantage? (ex: memory optimization)
Jersey Runtime server is Tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is extremely implementation specific, but from what I remember with both Jersey and CXF, File would make a copy, but is not subject to the vagaries of the HTTP connection, whereas InputStream does NOT make a copy, but could not be passed around to be consumed by other processes (because it's tied to the InputStream of the HTTP Request...)